# REST call using Vimscript

Tags: vimscript

Actually I'm using Python to make REST calls from inside Vim.

Is it possible use only Vimscript to make REST calls?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is "no". (Unless you count `system()` and `:!` as "only Vimscript".)

Comment: For making REST calls, I have been using https://github.com/nicwest/QQ.vim (though the author moved to another plugin vim-http).  Hope these plugins are useful, or are good as references to make REST calls inside Vim with a little help from Python scripts. ;)

Comment: take a look at this webapi: https://github.com/mattn/webapi-vim

Comment: @LiuSha thanks. I think that was the answer that I was looking for. Can you put as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @adelarsq, sorry I missed the message. Will do it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the use of vim extension [webapi](https://github.com/mattn/webapi-vim). The best way to install it is using any package manager and follow [vimawesome](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/webapi-vim).

The library contains various parser for different formats and is very easy to use with little configuration. Enjoy.